# ESLint picks up configuration from node_modules

Tags: eslint

I've these `devDependencies`:

```
{
   // ...
   "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^3.0.1",
   "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^3.0.1",
   "cordova-android": "^7.1.4",
   "eslint": "^7.1.0",
   "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.11.0",
   "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.2",
   "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.3",
   // ...
}
```

This is my `.eslintrc.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  extends: [
    'eslint:recommended',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
    'prettier/@typescript-eslint',
    'plugin:prettier/recommended'
  ],
  env: {
    browser: true,
    node: true
  },
  globals: {
    mocha: true,
  },
  parserOptions: {
    parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
    project: './tsconfig.json'
  },
  ignorePatterns: ['dist/*', 'dest/*', 'node_modules/*'],
  plugins: ['@typescript-eslint', 'prettier']
}
```

This is the `.prettierrc.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  printWidth: 80,
  tabWidth: 2,
  singleQuote: true,
  quoteProps: 'as-needed',
  trailingComma: 'none',
  bracketSpacing: true,
  semi: false,
  useTabs: false,
  jsxBracketSameLine: false,
  proseWrap: 'never'
}
```

If I run `npx eslint ./**/*.ts`, I get this error:

> Oops! Something went wrong! :(
>
> ESLint: 7.1.0
>
> ESLint couldn't find the config "semistandard" to extend from. Please
>   check that the name of the config is correct.
>
> The config "semistandard" was referenced from the config file in
>   "/Users/alex/src/my-app/node_modules/cordova-android/.eslintrc.yml".
>
> If you still have problems, please stop by https://eslint.org/chat to
>   chat with the team.

Why does ESLint try to pick this configuration inside a dependency from `node_modules` also I've added `node_modules` to the `ignorePatterns` in `.eslintrc.js`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Quoting the glob pattern fixed it:

```
npx eslint „**/*.ts“
```

This also works:

```
npx eslint . --ext .ts
```